# c++ pthread not working

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a classA which creates a thread and I want the thread running until a variable is set to false.

I create  the thread like:

```
ClassA::ClassA():
m_bContinue(true),
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&m_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&m_thWorkThread, NULL, &ClassA::ThreadProc, this);
}
```

I want thread running as long as pClassA->Continue() returns true.

```
void* ClassA::ThreadProc(void *p) //ThreadProc defined as static member function
{
    ClassA *pClassA = reinterpret_cast<ClassA*>(p);

    if(pClassA != NULL)
    {
        while(pClassA->Continue())
        {
            printf("in the while \n ");

        }
    }
    else
        printf("pClassA null \n");
}
```

Continue is returning m_bcontinue which set to true in the constructor.

```
bool ClassA::Continue()
{
   return bContinue;
}
```

When I run it, it only enters while loop once and prints "in the while" and program stops. When I do strace, I saw the message +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++. 
And when I change the while loop like:

```
while(1){}
```

it is working properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot launch member functions using `pthread_create`. Instead, use normal function, pass `this` to it and call the needed function:

```
void *ThreadProc (void *p)
{
  reinterpret_cast<ClassA*>(p)->ThreadProc (p);
  return 0;
}

...
pthread_create(&m_thWorkThread, NULL, &ThreadProc, this);
```

Or, instead you can use c++11 and its `std::thread` that allows launching class member functions.

Comment: What do you mean "normal function"? In my case I define ThreadProc as static member function. Do you mean defining another class with ThreadProc function?

Comment: @AvbAvb  Ah, it's static. By normal I meant non-member function, but static is fine too. Then your code is fine and it is crashing in that while loop probably because of heap corruption in some other place.

Answer (score 0):

Could the object of type A have a shorter lifetime than the thread ? It seems object A dies too soon. Using `while(1)`, you are no longer referencing A.

Answer (score 0):

Quick question. Where is pthread_join here. I hope you havent missed it. Just curious.